# Oracle Stored Procedure OUT CLOB return error character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have an Oracle stored procedure which I'm calling from an application. The stored procedure will search my the parameter given from the application and query out the data and then return the information message to my application.

However, I get an error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

on line 37, which is P_INFO and I'm using CLOB data type here, suppose it can support a very large amount of character, assuming the data return is more than 100k of characters.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SimpleProcedure
(
  P_ID  VARCHAR2,
  P_INFO OUT CLOB
) AS
  V_PROJ_ID   VARCHAR2(50);
  V_PROJ_NAME NVARCHAR2(1000);
  V_APP_ID     VARCHAR2(50);
  V_APP_STATUS VARCHAR2(50);
  CURSOR SUB_ATTACH_CURSOR(APP_ID VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT S.SUBMISSION_ID,
           SA.FILE_ID,
           SA.STATUS_CODE,
           E.FILENAME_TEXT
      FROM SUBM_ATTCHMNT SA
     INNER JOIN SUB_SUBMISSION S
        ON S.SUBMISSION_ID = SA.SUBMISSION_ID
     INNER JOIN SUB_FILE E
        ON E.FILE_ID = SA.FILE_ID
     WHERE S.APP_ID = APP_ID;
BEGIN
  SELECT P.PROJECT_ID,
         P.NAME_TEXT,
         A.APP_ID,
         A.STATUS_CODE
    INTO V_PROJ_ID, V_PROJ_NAME, V_APP_ID, V_APP_STATUS
    FROM SUB_APP A
   INNER JOIN SUB_PROJ P
      ON P.PROJECT_ID = A.PROJECT_ID
   WHERE A.ID = P_ID;
  P_INFO := 'Information:
               Proj id: ' || V_PROJ_ID || ',
               Proj name: ' || V_PROJ_NAME || ',
               App id: ' || V_APP_ID || ',
               App status: ' || V_APP_STATUS || ',';
  FOR SA IN SUB_ATTACH_CURSOR(V_APP_ID) LOOP
    P_INFO := P_INFO || 'Submission id: ' || SA.SUBMISSION_ID ||
                 ',file id: ' || SA.FILE_ID || ', file name: ' ||
                 SA.FILENAME_TEXT || ', file Status: ' ||
                 SA.STATUS_CODE || ' ';
  END LOOP;
END SimpleProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this (using [DBMS_LOB.APPEND](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm)):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SimpleProcedure(P_ID  VARCHAR2, P_INFO OUT CLOB) AS

  V_PROJ_ID   VARCHAR2(50);
  V_PROJ_NAME NVARCHAR2(1000);
  V_APP_ID     VARCHAR2(50);
  V_APP_STATUS VARCHAR2(50);
  v_SA VARCHAR2(30000); 

  CURSOR SUB_ATTACH_CURSOR(APP_ID VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT S.SUBMISSION_ID,
           SA.FILE_ID,
           SA.STATUS_CODE,
           E.FILENAME_TEXT
    ...
BEGIN
  SELECT P.PROJECT_ID,
         P.NAME_TEXT,
         A.APP_ID,
         A.STATUS_CODE
     ...    
  P_INFO := 'Information:
               Proj id: ' || V_PROJ_ID || ',
               Proj name: ' || V_PROJ_NAME || ',
               App id: ' || V_APP_ID || ',
               App status: ' || V_APP_STATUS || ',';
  FOR SA IN SUB_ATTACH_CURSOR(V_APP_ID) LOOP
    v_SA := 'Submission id: ' || SA.SUBMISSION_ID ||
                 ',file id: ' || SA.FILE_ID || ', file name: ' ||
                 SA.FILENAME_TEXT || ', file Status: ' ||
                 SA.STATUS_CODE || ' ';
    DBMS_LOB.APPEND(P_INFO, v_SA);
  END LOOP;
END SimpleProcedure;
```